# Group by join date + add month in where sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table:

**PERSON**

- ID
- Name
- date_created
- date_left

What I want is a list of all months and the amount of users joined and the amount of users that left.

I already have the following query: it returns the amount of new users that joined in the month that I pass:

```
select MONTH(date_created) 'Month', YEAR(date_created) 'Year', count(*) as 'New Users'
from person p 
where YEAR(date_created) = 2018 and MONTH( p.date_created) = 5
group by MONTH(date_created), YEAR(date_created)
```

It returns what I want:

[image]

How would I edit this to include a year report and add the column 'Users left' next to the 'new users' one?

My result would be:

```
MONTH YEAR NEW USERS  USERS LEFT
1    2019  10          5
```

Comment: I am not able to see the Image ? Can any one see it ?

Comment: Can you provide some sample data and expected results please? We don't know your database schema, so we can't help you without more information. On a different note, I would avoid things like `YEAR(date_created)` in your `WHERE` clause; using things like that cause your query to be non-SARGable resulting in your indexes being ignored and thus performance being poor.

Comment: This is the image https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTQCp.png

Comment: You've added expected results, but the sample data and schema is the really important thing here. We only know that your table has 1 column right now, `date_created`. That column alone is not going to tell us when a user left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would "unpivot" the data using `cross apply`:

```
select v.[year], v.[month], sum(v.iscreated) as num_created,
       sum(v.isleft) as num_left
from person p cross apply
     (values (year(p.date_created), month(p.date_created), 1, 0),
             (year(p.date_left), month(p.date_left), 0, 1)
     ) v([year], [month], iscreated, isleft)
group by v.[year], v.[month]
order by v.[year], v.[month];
```

Answer (score 2):

The straight-forward approach is probably to full outer join all entries and all leaves. SQL Server makes this a bit awkward by not featuring `USING`, so we must use `ON` and `COALESCE` on month and year instead.

```
select
  coalesce(pin.year, pout.year) as year,
  coalesce(pin.month, pout.month) as month,
  coalesce(pin.cnt, 0) as count_in,
  coalesce(pout.cnt, 0) as count_out
from
(
  select year(date_created) as year, month(date_created) as month, count(*) as cnt
  from person 
  group by year(date_created), month(date_created)
) pin
full outer join
(
  select year(date_left) as year, month(date_left) as month, count(*) as cnt
  from person
  group by month(date_left), year(date_left)
) pout on pout.year = pin.year and pout.month = pin.month
order by year, month;
```

Comment: your query returns an error at the `) in` line, it says `EXPECTING AS, ID or QUOTED ID`

Comment: Ah, yes, `IN` is a reserved word. I've updated my answer and changed the table aliases.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could do it with a SubSelect? Tried it right now with ORACLE Syntax, I'm not sure if it works in SQL-Server.

```
SELECT * FROM 
( 
    select MONTH(date_created) 'Month_C', YEAR(date_created) 'Year_C', count(*) as 'New Users'
    from person p 
    where YEAR(date_created) = 2018 and MONTH( p.date_created) = 5
    group by MONTH(date_created), YEAR(date_created)
)created_user,
(
    select MONTH(date_left) 'Month_L', YEAR(date_left) 'Year_L', count(*) as 'New Users'
    from person p 
    where YEAR(date_left) = 2018 and MONTH( p.date_left) = 5
    group by MONTH(date_left), YEAR(date_left)
) left_user
where created_user.Year_C = left_user.Year_L
and created_user.Month_C = left_user.Month_L
```